# Highcharts: How to shift yAxis to center (e.g.Population by sex and age group)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

similar to official demo.

[Bar with negative stack | Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-negative-stack)

want to shift yAxis(age) to center.

like this [2011 Census - Office for National Statistics](http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/resources/figure3s_tcm77-292369.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Highcharts does not support such a chart type. However, you can create it using two bar charts aligned horizontally. Check demo I posted you below.

HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="cnt">
  <div id="container1"></div>
  <div id="container2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container1,
#container2 {
  width: 49%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#cnt {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

JS:

```
var categories = [
  '0-4', '5-9', '10-14', '15-19',
  '20-24', '25-29', '30-34', '35-39', '40-44',
  '45-49', '50-54', '55-59', '60-64', '65-69',
  '70-74', '75-79', '80-84', '85-89', '90-94',
  '95-99', '100 + '
];

Highcharts.chart('container1', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    marginRight: 1
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    reversed: true,
    title: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    visible: false,
    reversed: false,
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'left',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    x: 30,
    y: 10,
    floating: true,
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
    shadow: true
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    pointPadding: 0,
    groupPadding: 0,
    name: 2011,
    data: [
      2.1, 2.0, 2.1, 2.3, 2.6,
      2.9, 3.2, 3.1, 2.9, 3.4,
      4.3, 4.0, 3.5, 2.9, 2.5,
      2.7, 2.2, 1.1, 0.6, 0.2,
      0.0
    ]
  }, {
    type: 'line',
    color: '#000',
    name: 2001,
    marker: {
      enabled: false
    },
    data: [
      1.1, 1.0, 1.1, 2.1, 2.2,
      2.4, 2.2, 3.1, 1.9, 2.4,
      4.3, 4.7, 2.5, 2.2, 2.0,
      2.1, 2.0, 1.5, 1.6, 1.2,
      0.0
    ]
  }]
});

Highcharts.chart('container2', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    enabled: false,
    title: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    reversed: false,
    categories: categories,
    tickLength: 0
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    x: -20,
    y: 10,
    floating: true,
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
    shadow: true
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    color: '#ccaadd',
    pointPadding: 0,
    groupPadding: 0,
    name: 2011,
    data: [
      2.1, 2.0, 2.1, 2.3, 2.6,
      2.9, 3.2, 3.1, 2.9, 3.4,
      4.3, 4.0, 3.5, 2.9, 2.5,
      2.7, 2.2, 1.1, 0.6, 0.2,
      0.0
    ]
  }, {
    type: 'line',
    color: '#000',
    name: 2001,
    marker: {
      enabled: false
    },
    data: [
      1.1, 1.0, 1.1, 2.1, 2.2,
      2.4, 2.2, 3.1, 1.9, 2.4,
      4.3, 4.7, 2.5, 2.2, 2.0,
      2.1, 2.0, 1.5, 1.6, 1.2,
      0.0
    ]
  }]
});
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1fun4t0e/

Comment: thanks! But there are still three things I want to settle.
Demo: [https://jsfiddle.net/matamatak/w67ame3c](https://jsfiddle.net/matamatak/w67ame3c)

1.Add percentage on tooltip
2.Set Legend(man,woman,age) at the top.
3.Same value,  same length.
Woman data is equal to man data. But bars are slightly different lengths.

[Like this](https://i.imgur.com/OpjAz1K.png)

Comment: 1. Percentage of man and women separately or both? You can calculate it looping through your data and then use `tooltip.formatter` (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter) to calculate the percentage you need for each bar. 2. One legend with both man, woman and age? It will require to create a custom legend and use `chart.series.hide()' and `chart.series.show()` (https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#hide). 3. Yes, because both charts have the same percentage width set in css. The right one has axis labels and the same width, you have to adjust it.